# Adventure Works 2012 Analysis Services Tutorial Deployment - How to change datasource from localhost to AdWorks?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

I have successfully installed SQL Server 2012 and attached the AdventureWorksDW2012 database. On trying to deploy the Analysis Services Tutorial Lesson 1 the solution builds but fails to deploy from Visual Studio 2010 because the server is 'localhost'. 'localhost' is listed in the AdventureWorks 2012 XML in the Analysis Services Data Source - what should it be changed to, to point to the AdventureWorksDW2012 database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure two things: database as a data source and the analysis services server to deploy to cube (analysis services database).

Probably you have a problem with Analysis Services server connection string. To change the server address right click on your SSAS project and than click the properties (alt+enter), than go to COnfiguration Properties and than go to Deployment tab and change the server name.
For more read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166576.aspx

If you will have the problem with the data source database. You need to double click on your data source and change the server name and/or credintials.